# If $A^2B+1973AB^2+2019AB+I_n=0$, then both $A$ and $B$ are invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n \times n$ matrices. Prove that

If $A^2B+1973AB^2+2019AB+I_n=0$, then both $A$ and $B$ are invertible.

My initial thoughts would be to take  $det(A^2B)+det(1973AB^2)+det(2019AB)+det(I_n)=det(0)$ , but $det(A+B)\neq det (A) +det(B)$ so I'm not sure how to proceed

Comment: Have you tried factorising? There seems to be a common $AB$ term...

Comment: so after factorising can I say that $(det(AB))(det(A+1973B+2019))=det(-I_n)$ and since the RHS $\neq 0$, then $det(AB) \neq 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that

$$A (-AB -1973B^2-2019B) =I_n. $$

Can you find a similar equation for $B$?